# Google Drive: getting content of  (an existing) file results in 404 response error

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse, google-drive-api

i have a file in my drive that has a "public" visibility. im using the code (below) from the examples page for the drive api to retreive the files content. the file meta data shows me that my file is there. but the hhtp response tells me its not there (The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.).(oh by the way the file was uploaded by a user with "owner" permissions, and now im trying to retrieve the same file with a different user with "writer" permissions.)any thoughts?

```
    public static System.IO.Stream DownloadFile(
     IAuthenticator authenticator, Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file.DownloadUrl))
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(file.DownloadUrl));
                authenticator.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(request);
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    return response.GetResponseStream();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "An error occurred: " + response.StatusDescription);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the URL or URI of the file param that you are passing by chance..?

Comment: downloadurl:https://doc-14-bg-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/j84hv5viidsfdmdru1q99l7gkhosnk89/s2d30240qmrutrjtvp19ofbsuqm414cl/1348862400000/08997206022972546298/11782003897876651330/0B3Y2w6gu0G3VX1VWMzZCUUxnUlU?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of problem, try it using the form at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it

That way you can determine if it's a problem with your code or with the file.